# Do I need to complete a Subject that is only used to compose another Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi I have the following component:

```js
export class PreviewReportComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() params: PreviewParams;
  reload$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  preview$: Observable<SafeHtml>;
  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.preview$ = this.reload$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      startWith([null]),
      switchMap(() => this.reportService.getPreview(this.params)),
    );
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.reload$.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.reload$.complete();
  }
}
```

Do I need to implements OnDestroy and call complete on reload$ subject?

Im already using AsyncPipe to subscribe to preview$ Observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to implements OnDestroy and call complete on reload$ subject?

If your concern was memory leaks, then NO, it's not necessary to implement `OnDestroy` to complete your subject, since you are not subscribing in your component. Memory leaks occur when you have Subscriptions that are left open after the component is destroyed.

Since you are using `AsyncPipe` to handle subscriptions, you don't need to worry about it.

---

Actually, you don't even need `OnInit`:

```js
export class PreviewReportComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() params: PreviewParams;

  private reload$ = new Subject<void>();

  public preview$ = this.reload$.pipe(
    startWith([null]),
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap(() => this.reportService.getPreview(this.params)),
  );

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.reload$.next();
  }

}
```

You could also get rid of `OnChanges` as well, if you change the params to be a setter:

```js
export class PreviewReportComponent {
  private params$ = new Subject<PreviewParams>();

  @Input() set params(params: PreviewParams) {
    this.params$.next(params);
  }

  public preview$ = this.params$.pipe(
    startWith([null]),
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap(params => this.reportService.getPreview(params)),
  );

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code refactoring!